# Testing Java Serial Port Program

Tags: java, serial-port

I have done the code to read byte streams from serial ports.The problem is I am unable to test the code as I dont have a device that interacts with these ports..

**I have already used emulator** but on running the code and the emulator **nothing happens.There is no progress and no error.**

**Here is the code**

```
class SimpleRead implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener{
    CommPortIdentifier portId;
    Enumeration       portList;
    InputStream           inputStream;
    SerialPort            serialPort;
    Thread            readThread;

    /**
     * Method declaration
     *
     *
     * @param args
     *
     * @see
     */
    public void main(String[] args) {
    boolean           portFound = false;
    String            defaultPort = "/dev/term/a";

    if (args.length > 0) {
        defaultPort = args[0];
    } 

    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
        if (portId.getName().equals(defaultPort)) {
            jTextArea1.setText("Found port: "+defaultPort);
            portFound = true;
            SimpleRead reader = new SimpleRead();
        } 
        } 
    } 
    if (!portFound) {
        jTextArea1.setText("port " + defaultPort + " not found.");
    } 

    } 

    /**
     * Constructor declaration
     *
     *
     * @see
     */
    public SimpleRead() {
    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {}

    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    try {
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {}

    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

    try {
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, 
                       SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, 
                       SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {}

    readThread = new Thread(this);

    readThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Method declaration
     *
     *
     * @see
     */
    public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    } 

    /**
     * Method declaration
     *
     *
     * @param event
     *
     * @see
     */
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch (event.getEventType()) {

    case SerialPortEvent.BI:

    case SerialPortEvent.OE:

    case SerialPortEvent.FE:

    case SerialPortEvent.PE:

    case SerialPortEvent.CD:

    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:

    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:

    case SerialPortEvent.RI:

    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;

    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];

        try {
        while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
            int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
        } 

        jTextArea1.setText(new String(readBuffer));
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        break;
    }
    } 

}
```

**Note:** I am using javax.comm and Netbeans IDE.
Thank You

Comment: Until you have the actual device its unlikely we can help you.  I have to downvote this for being unable to do the required research before asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is I am unable to test the code as I dont have a device that interacts with these ports..

The only real solution is to get some devices.  Seriously, testing with an emulator will only get you so far, even assuming that the emulator works.  It would be totally irresponsible to sell or deliver code that you haven't tested with real devices.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a null modem cable (cross-over cable) between your 2 serial ports on the computer, or if you only have one, run the cable from another computer.

Now either create a sending program to push data through the null modem cable, or use another method to push the data.  For example, in linux you could cat a file to a serial port:  cat data.dat > /dev/ttyS0

Answer (score 0):

You have to test with a real device or the testing is next to worthless. Just buy a PCI card with a serial port, you can get them for about $5.